# undefined index notice stops script

Tags: php

Ok guys this is my code:

```
if (!is_array($html_strings[$form_name])) {$html_strings[$form_name] = array();}
        array_push($html_strings[$form_name], "<input type='checkbox' ".
                                                " name='" . $result{"formdir"} . "_" . $result{"form_id"} . "'".
                                                " id='" . $result{"formdir"} . "_" . $result{"form_id"} . "'".
                                                " value='" . $result{"encounter"} . "'" .
                                                " class='encounter_form' ".
                                                ">" . xl_form_title($result{"form_name"}) . "<br>\n");
```

and I am getting the following notice ***"Notice: Undefined index: Nota de Consulta"***

Any help on fixing this issue?

Comment: where do you set `$form_name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$html_strings['Nota de Consulta']` seems to be not defined yet, so you can't use `is_array` on it.

You can check if `$html_strings[$form_name]` exists, before checking it for being an array:

```
if (!isset($html_strings[$form_name]) || !is_array($html_strings[$form_name])) {
    $html_strings[$form_name] = array();
}
```